# iPhone Local Notification loop: reset fireDate after device shows notification alert

Tags: iphone, loops, notifications, local, repeat

after studying apple's "Local and Push Notifications in Depth" and loads of forum postings,
i still cannot figure this out:

- my application schedules a notification in 10" at startup in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
- if the app stays open, didReceiveLocalNotification is called after 10" and i can start another notification there. good.
- if the app is in the background, the system alert pops up.

  - if i click "View", didReceiveLocalNotification is also called and i can schedule the next notification. good.
  - if i click "Close", nothing is called so far and i cannot renew the notification.
    BAD.

i wonder, how i can capture the Close button event from the system's local notification alert popup.

any ideas?
TIA
dave

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. 
You can use recurring notification or schedule up to 64 for local notifications in advance and cancel/reschedule as needed.

Comment: that's a pity. i would say that local notification urgently needs some work done by apple. recurring can only be done once per minute/hour/day/etc... no good solution for me.

Comment: Well, if a user decides to ignore 64 of your notifications they probably don't care much about what you have to say.